# Read input text into an array of words and get rid of punctuation marks

Tags: c, arrays, input, punctuation

There's this giant code I found on the internet.. It's a program that finds n most frequent words in a file and prints them out. The following program reads the given text file, but I want to write the input text by myself, so I am probably going to store the words in an array. How do I do that so that the program would read the text of random length and the following program would still work? And also if there were punctuation marks in the  input text, I would have to get rid of them, so the text wouldn't consist of only the letters from 'a' to 'z'. Do I even need the `MAX_CHARS` constant then?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

# define MAX_CHARS 26
# define MAX_WORD_SIZE 32000


// A utility function to show results, The min heap
// contains n most frequent words so far, at any time
void displayMinHeap( MinHeap* minHeap )
{
    int i;

    // print top N word with frequency
    for( i = 0; i < minHeap->count; ++i )
    {
        printf( "%s %d\n", minHeap->array[i].word,
                            minHeap->array[i].frequency );
    }
}

// The main funtion that takes a file as input, add words to heap
// and Trie, finally shows result from heap
void printKMostFreq( FILE* fp, int n )
{
    // Create a Min Heap of Size n
    MinHeap* minHeap = createMinHeap( n );

    // Create an empty Trie
    TrieNode* root = NULL;

    // A buffer to store one word at a time
    char buffer[MAX_WORD_SIZE];

    // Read words one by one from file.  Insert the word in Trie and Min Heap
    while( fscanf( fp, "%s", buffer ) != EOF )
        insertTrieAndHeap(buffer, &root, minHeap);

    // The Min Heap will have the n most frequent words, so print Min Heap nodes
    displayMinHeap( minHeap );
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    FILE *fp = fopen ("file.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        printf ("File doesn't exist ");
    else
        printKMostFreq (fp, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: TL;DR! Please narrow down the code to the parts where you have your problem, or better yet please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: The code you show lacks some parts, e.g. the definitions of `MinHeap`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to modify this program to do what you want, but I'm not going to do that for you, at least not without being paid. For a simple solution, try to generate your text and write it to a text file. You can then pass the content of that file into the word counting software. You can also use pipes to do that.

Comment: @lol What operating system are you working on? Google can tell you what pipes are. You won't get far in programming without consulting documentation and *reading* a lot.